# Using AutoHotkey to map F12 to ALT + {=} (Onenote equation shortcut )

Tags: autohotkey, microsoft-onenote

I have tried

> F12::   Send, {LAlt Down}{=}{LAlt Up}

which was recored by Macro creator but did not work. Also a variety of changes like !{=} , !=, and SendPlay as well.
It seems it is not possible to remap Alt + = in Onenote using Autohotkey. However, those with Ctrl shortcut can be mapped with Autohotkey though.
Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Both `F12:: Send {LAlt Down}{=}{LAlt Up}` and `F12:: Send !=` worked equally well for me. After you added the mapping to your script file did you tell autohotkey to reload it?

Comment: Did you try it in Onenote ? The problem is somehow it is not possible to remap Alt shortcut in Onenote application.

Comment: Yes, @user1502776 I tested it in Onenote (Onenote 2010) and it worked fine. If I hit F12 it opened up the equation editor.

Comment: I don't understand but it works now. Really strange indeed. Thanks Glenn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code that I use and I few others. Please feel free to change the F-shortcut to fit your habits:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Framework::CFrame
F12::
;Insert Math equation
Send, {LAlt Down}{=}{LAlt Up}
return

F1::
;Insert boxed table
Send, !nt{Right}{Enter}{Right}
return

F2::
;Make table borderless
Send, !jh
return

F3::
;Bring up Table Layout tab
Send, !j
return

F4::
;Bringup Math menu
Send, !j
return
#IfWinActive
```